# Easily add words to dictionary in Word

Tags: dictionary, microsoft-word-2013

I am adding new words into the dictionary in Microsoft Word. But if I add **foo**, **Foo** does not get automatically added. Is there an option for this, or is Word just being stupid?

If the latter and Word cannot do even this simple thing, how can I add a macro that will take the currently selected word (which can be **foo** or **Foo**) and add both forms (lower-case and first letter capitalised) into the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Use Auto Correct feature to do such things like this.

It could be available in Tools menu (previous versions of Office 2007). For the newer versions of Office, this could be found on Proofing option pane from Word Option.

> Click Office Button / File Button (Office 2010 or higher) of MS-Word >
>   Options > Proofing

Comment: But for auto correct also I have to add rule foo = Foo myself every time. Also sometime I want foo and sometime Foo in middle of sentence so auto correct is not helpful.